# Managing email domains in teams documentation needs work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000061151-how-to-manage-email-domains-for-auto-joining-the-team

First sentence:

> **All admin** can manage the domains that allow users to automatically join a Team. This page can be accessed by navigating to 'Settings' ->
>   'Invite'.

Should probably say Any admin or All admin**s**

Comment: Could you please compile these all into *one* bug report and submit them all at once? Separating them all out for minor errors is just causing a flood of questions in several internal chat rooms.

Comment: I didn't know questions went to chat rooms - is that a new feature?

Comment: @JonH: We're using a feature that's been around for ages: [RSS feeds](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=feeds). In this case, we're feeding new [meta-tag:stackoverflow-for-teams] questions into our chat rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.